# Unity3D get animator controller current Animation time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi All I was trying to build an app and try to do things on the scroll.

I am having 3 different layers in the Animator Controller of the Unity all weight 1. In the first layer having the on-load animation and in the layer 2 having the on scroll animation which need to be played on top of the layer 1 animation along with it.

So to call the animation on scroll I have written a program which is calling the animation in the bases of the scroll so animation on the layer 2 "take001" is getting played on scroll depend upon how much scroll happened.

Now I want to get the current Time of the layer 2 animation.

Find the code below and the screenshot of the layers I have created in the Unity:

[Refer Img] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1huCM.jpg

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class MouseMovementScript : MonoBehaviour {
Animator anim;
AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo;
AnimatorClipInfo[] myAnimatorClip;
double speedBase = 1;
void Start () {
     anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
     stateInfo = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(1);
    //Output the name of the starting clip

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    var d = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");

    if (d > 0f)
    {

        Time.timeScale = 1;
        anim.SetFloat("Direction", 1.0f);
        anim.Play("take001");
        StartCoroutine(TestCoroutine(d));

        anim.Play("BoxAnimation001");
    }
    else if (d < 0f)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        anim.SetFloat("Direction", -1.0f);
    }

     // Cursor
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if(Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit))
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            if(hit.transform.tag == "Popup_1")
            {
                Application.ExternalCall("OpenPopup", 0);
            } 
            else if(hit.transform.tag == "Popup_2")
            {
                Application.ExternalCall("OpenPopup", 1);
            } 
            else if(hit.transform.tag == "Popup_3")
            {
                Application.ExternalCall("OpenPopup", 2);
            } 
            else if(hit.transform.tag == "Popup_4")
            {
                Application.ExternalCall("OpenPopup", 3);
            } 
        }
    }
}


IEnumerator TestCoroutine(float d){
 yield return new WaitForSeconds(d);
 Time.timeScale = 0; } }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way is to divide the current animation state normalized time with `1` and return the remainder from the division.

```
public float GetCurrentAnimatorTime(Animator targetAnim, int layer = 0)
{
    AnimatorStateInfo animState = targetAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(layer);
    float currentTime = animState.normalizedTime % 1;
    return currentTime;
}
```

This works most of the time but I've seen places where it didn't work as expected

---

The proper way to do this is a bit complicated because Unity don't give you access the `AnimationClip` used by the `Animator` and you need the `AnimationClip` to retrieve the current time by multiplying `AnimationClip.length` with `AnimationState.normalizedTime`;.

To do this, you have to keep reference of the `AnimationClip` you used in a public variable. Create a dictionary that uses `Animator.StringToHash` as key and the corresponding `AnimationClip` as value. To obtain the current `AnimationClip`, pass `Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo.fullPathHash` to the Dictionary and it will give you the proper `AnimationClip`. This clip you can use to obtain the current time by multiplying its length the `AnimationState.normalizedTime`.

---

Your `AnimationClip` references:

```
public AnimationClip jumpClip;
public AnimationClip moveClip;
public AnimationClip lookClip;
```

Get the animation state hash for each Animation State:

```
const string animBaseLayer = "Base Layer";
int jumpAnimHash = Animator.StringToHash(animBaseLayer + ".Jump");
int moveAnimHash = Animator.StringToHash(animBaseLayer + ".Move");
int lookAnimHash = Animator.StringToHash(animBaseLayer + ".Look");
```

Dictionary to link the each animation state hash with their AnimationClip:

```
Dictionary<int, AnimationClip> hashToClip = new Dictionary<int, AnimationClip>();
```

Initialize the `Dictionary` in the `Awake` function:

```
void Awake()
{
    hashToClip.Add(jumpAnimHash, jumpClip);
    hashToClip.Add(moveAnimHash, moveClip);
    hashToClip.Add(lookAnimHash, lookClip);
}
```

Function to obtain `AnimationClip`  from the animation state hash:

```
AnimationClip GetClipFromHash(int hash)
{
    AnimationClip clip;
    if (hashToClip.TryGetValue(hash, out clip))
        return clip;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Finally, a function to get the current Animator time:

```
public float GetCurrentAnimatorTime(Animator targetAnim, int layer = 0)
{
    AnimatorStateInfo animState = targetAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(layer);
    //Get the current animation hash
    int currentAnimHash = animState.fullPathHash;

    //Convert the animation hash to animation clip
    AnimationClip clip = GetClipFromHash(currentAnimHash);

    //Get the current time
    float currentTime = clip.length * animState.normalizedTime;
    return currentTime;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
public Animator anim;

void Update()
{
    float time = GetCurrentAnimatorTime(anim, 0);
    Debug.Log(time);
}
```

Comment: Hi [Programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3785314/programmer) thanks for your comment. I was trying the "animState.normalizedTime" but in my case it is returning always 0.

Also I have multiple animations like 3 .anim files in unity on 3 different layers in the animator. In that scenario how I will get the 2nd layers animation time. 

Sorry I am a bit new to Unity so might be not making any sense to you.

Comment: Thanks [Programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3785314/programmer) this was very helpful and working fine. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Saw your comment but didn't know what to tell you because this works for me and is what I've been using. By the way, you can pass the layer to the second parameter of the `GetCurrentAnimatorTime` function in my answer. The layer starts from 0 like array. The next layer is 1 and the next is 2. In my example, I passed 0 to it since that's the first layer. You can pass your layer to it. Also, where I had `const string animBaseLayer = "Base Layer";`, you have to replace `"Base Layer"` with the name of your layer.